# Firefox iframe parent.location not working?

Tags: facebook, firefox, iframe, facebook-apps

I cannot seem to get an iframe in firefox(MAC) to return to its parent page, ive tried

```
this.parent.location = 'page'+msg;
```

every time I trigger the above in Firefox(MAC) I get a "NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE" message, it works in every browser apart from that!

any ideas?